# search page on real estate web portal using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, activestate

i want to create a advance search page on my real estate web portal
search will be done with different criteria like search using zip code search by google maps an so on
kindly help me to do this should i make 3 or 4 different pages for each search if not how can i display them on single page?
if there is any sample code or helping guide

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many search critieria you want and if you want to enable the user of the site to combine searches together you can add the text fields/dropdowns on a search widget in the master page which when submitted goes to the results page or at the top of a defined search page. Once the user has entered the information they want to search on then you can take the values from the defined search criteria and process in c#/sql as required.

Hope this helps